# GET variable not parsing

Tags: php

I cant seem to understand why I have received this error.This seems to work for the `$pid` variable but not for `$type`.

Update: I have fixed the error but now the concatenated variable ' . $type . ''; in the link below is not showing at all on the page.

Line 5 is:

```
$page=$_GET["type"];
```

Code:

```
 if (!$_GET["type"]){
 $page="";
 }else{
$page=$_GET["type"];
}

  $sqlCommand="SELECT id,Type FROM cart WHERE Type='$page'";
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());
 $menu ="";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$pid=$row["id"];
  $type=$row["Type"];

  $menu= '<a STYLE="text-decoration:none; color:white" href="pt.php?pid=1&type=' .       $type .    '">' . $type . '</a>';
 $menu2= '<a STYLE="text-decoration:none; color:white" href="pt.php?pid=7&type=' .     $type . '">' . $type . '/a>';
```

Comment: `var_dump($_GET);` and post the output please.

Comment: what is line 5? also, you should use `isset($_GET['type'])`

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Are you sure "type" is being passed in properly? Maybe try this for the first IF constraint: `if (!isset($_GET['type'])) {` instead

Comment: Ok, so you delete your post that has lots of comments and an answer and ask the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141705/get-variable-not-passing-variable-but-will-parse-id-variable

Comment: Line 5 is on the question description

Comment: I get an undefined error at echo $var_dump($_GET);

Comment: it's `var_dump` not `$var_dump`

Comment: var_dump It returns 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will give you PHP Notice Undefined index if it can't find 'type' key in the $_GET global variable. If you don't want this notice - try to do

```
if (! isset($_GET["type"]))
{
...
}
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error But now I have a second error

Answer (score 0):

If you were to `var_dump($_GET)`, you will likely find the there is no entry to "type".  The error is telling you that `$_GET` array does not have an entry for this.

Answer (score 0):

your issue seem to be with

```
$sqlCommand="SELECT id,Type FROM cart WHERE Type='$page'";
```

sometimes,

> you pass NO $page variable

, so you get this error

you should set some default value to $page ..something like

```
if(!isset($_GET["type"])){
 $page="default";
 }else{
$page=$_GET["type"];
}
```

`default` will hold `default` contents for your page

Comment: This may be 'a' issue, but it's not the solution to the OP's stated problem.

Comment: @UnholyRanger hopes my updated answer addresses it

Comment: Ive done what you've said still  same error

Answer (score 0):

For `$_GET['type']` to be set, the URL must look like: `http://domain.tld/someplace.php?type=stuff`

Also, proper testing for it is so:

```
if(isset($_GET['type'])
    $page=$_GET['type'];
else
    $page = "";
```

Comment: I have concatenated the type url variable see original question

Comment: the first part is for general knowledge (anyone who reads the answer) and the second part is what you should try.

Comment: I have done second part of your answer and gets rid of the undefined index. However The variable $type is not outputting to the page why isnt it being recondnised by the GET variable? $menu= '<a STYLE="text-decoration:none; color:white" href="pt.php?pid=1&type=' . $type . '">' . $type . '</a>';

Comment: Well if the user goes to `pt.php` (notice no `?type=`) for the first time, `$type` is not set. Then all the links will not be set, so it is a loop of it not being set. Without knowing more on the system, there is not much more I can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark-Evans; V_K's reply is marked as the answer. I prefer to use a ternary operator:

```
$page = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : '';
```

If $_GET['type'] is set, it's assigned to $page. I prefer this to loops like

```
if(!isset($_GET['type'])) {...} else {...}
```

PS: don't forget to mysql_real_escape_string() your $page var in the query! Or better, use mysqi and prepared statements. The ext/mysql functions are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. This'll prevent SQL injection and cross site scripting attacks (a bit).